# jQuery removing an element and renumbering remaining elements

Tags: jquery, reverse, each

Does anyone see the flaw in my code here, because this one has me stumped!

```
function removeMLRow(rowNo) {
    $('#ml_organize li:eq(' + (rowNo - 1) + ')').remove();
    $($('#ml_organize li:eq(' + (rowNo) + ')').get().reverse()).each(function() {
        var newID = 'li' + ($(this).index() - 1);
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
    });
}
```

Comment: You should state what the problem is, does it throw an error? If so include it, is it not behaving right? Then describe what it *should* be doing and what's incorrect about it's current behavior.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Nick, All: I am attempting to remove an LI element from a list and then renumber that list based on the "li" element id. Once a row gets removed, it seems to lose track of where that row was in the list and skips it's position when iterating through the remaining "li"s.
For example, when I use my addMLRow function, results are fine: li1,li2,li3,li4,li5,li6,li7,li8,li9,li10,li11,li12,li13,li14,li15.
When I fire off the removeMLRow function, I get this result:
li2,li0,li4,li5,li6,li7,li8,li9,li10,li11,li12,li13,li14,li15
Note: I performed both functions on "li1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick, you were ALMOST there! Needed to (+1) instead of (-1) in the newID.

```
function removeMLRow(rowNo) {
    $('#ml_organize li').eq(rowNo - 1).remove();
    $('#ml_organize li').slice(rowNo - 1).each(function() {
        var newID = 'li' + ($(this).index() + 1);
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
    });
    var item_positions = $('#ml_organize').sortable('toArray');
    alert(item_positions);
}
```

Thanks to all for your help!

Comment: Thanks, Nick... feel free to delete this one.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say for sure based on the question, but I *think* this is what you're after:

```
function removeMLRow(rowNo) {
    $('#ml_organize li').eq(rowNo - 1).remove();
    $('#ml_organize li').slice(rowNo -1).each(function() {
        var newID = 'li' + ($(this).index() + 1);
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
    });
}
```

First, you can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) to just make things cleaner.  Then we're using [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get all the `<li>` elements *after* the one we removed and are numbering only those `<li>`'s.  You could use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) (greater-than-index), but [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) just trims down on the string concatenation (and is a bit faster, infinitesimal difference though).

Comment: Love the .eq() rather than the modified selector but here's my results now: li-1,li0,li1,li2,li3,li4,li5,li6,li7,li8,li9,li10,li11,li12

Comment: @Dave - I updated to give the correct numbering, wasn't sure what your indexes were based on, the +1 should work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you should be using reverse.  from what i see you're removing an element and then renumbering back to the top.  should you be renumbering to the bottom or are the numbers reversed?

more info please @dave