# Renumbering divs with Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, iteration

I found a thread on S.O. similar to what I need here. [jQuery removing an element and renumbering remaining elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392461/jquery-removing-an-element-and-renumbering-remaining-elements)

The above uses jQuery which we don't use so I'm not sure how to translate this idea of div renumbering to Dojo.

I inherited a massive web project that makes extensive use of Dojo 1.5. I totally dig what I understand of it so far but I have a question.

We have a page with numbered divs that I am successfully able to remove and delete the divs from. What I am needing though are divs in sequential order. Here's an example of what I need to re-div

```
<div id="filter_9_values_2_div">
<div id="filter_9_values_1_div">
<div id="filter_9_values_4_div">
```

Ideally in my javascript routine where I delete a div, I'd like to rename these in order so they look like this....

```
<div id="filter_9_values_1_div">
<div id="filter_9_values_2_div">
<div id="filter_9_values_3_div">
```

Does anyone have any idea how I would pull this off? I know how to successfully add a new div and make it unique but the idea of rewriting the divs is a complete mystery to me. As always many thanks in advance for the help. Janie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dojo.query('div').forEach(function(el, index){
   dojo.attr(el, "id", "filter_9_values_" + (index + 1) + "_div"); 
});
```

You might want to use something more specific as a query rather then using just "div" and if you needed more generic ID rather then having the "filter_9_values_..._div" you'd have to use regexp or split to build the string you want but this should give you the basic idea how to iterate over a collection of DOM elements and perform any action on them you could imagine.

Comment: Thanks Tom: Only problem with this is that it turns EVERY div on my page into a new number. What I need to renumber are divs that match "filter_9_values_(somenumber)_div". Any idea how I pull that off? Thank you so much again.. JW

Comment: @Jane Wilkie - as I've wrote you have to tighten your selector `dojo.query('div')` to target divs you need do the divs you have have a common parent with specific class? You could use a selector like `dojo.query('.parentClass div')`, or can you add a class to them so you can captuer all of them easily with selector such as `dojo.query('div.className')`. Basically the dojo selectors have pretty much the same structure as CSS selectors

Comment: Awesome Tom! Thanks so much! I realized that shortly after I posted that. You've got the answer and I really appreciate it. . JW

Comment: @JaneWilkie - you can also provide a node as a second parameter when querying: `dojo.query("div", dojo.byId("parentNodeId"))`. It will cause executing the query only on children of that node.